# Currency culture issue

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble finding the .net currency code for `Zambian kwacha`.

I have a database table which maintain these for each currency so my application can display figures with correct currency symbol i.e $150.00, £125.50 etc.

Currently have stored these like:

```
USD     en-US
GBP     en-GB
HKD     zh-HK
```

likewise

What I do it my code is:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(symbol);
```

Then use it to display like:

```
XXX.ToString("C2", culture);
```

Is there way I can find this?

Comment: I am marking this question down because its purely lazy and voting to close but look at https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+culture+codes&rlz=1C1GCEA_enSE816GB816&oq=.net+culter&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8, which is also something you could have done

Comment: @SimonPrice: Posting the question here, because could not find it in google!

Comment: Those are *cultures*, not currencies. You need to find the *culture*. A culture's name is the two-letter language code followed by the two-letter *country* code. And yes, you can find Zambia's country code in Google.

Comment: I suspect you should read how cultures work in .NET. You can get a list of installed cultures with `CultureInfo.GetCultures()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to format it, but the currency is `ZWM` and the culture is `en-ZM` for English.

Comment: Hi, I get `Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-ZM is an invalid culture identifier`

Comment: @unknown works for me: `123.ToString("C2",new CultureInfo("en-ZM"))` returns `K123.00`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Windows server 2012R2 and .net 4.6.1

Comment: @unknown and, what did you try? Did you use `en-ZM` or just `ZM`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Same thing as you suggested `en-ZM`